# Custom Flutter tab bar

Tags: flutter, tabs

I want to build a tab bar in which when user moves to another tab the icons of unselected tab changes and when the user selects it the icon changes for example :- I have a tab bar in which there is two tabs the first one is home and second is cart . When user moves from home to cart then home icon changes to settings or some other icon i want . how should i achieve it

Comment: Can you show your effort, what you've tried so far, and a visual representation

Comment: Pretty easy, just provide a variable to icon color property in Tab and change the variable color of selected and unselected in  "onTap: (index) {}," in TabBar. Note- Here the onTap will provide the selected tab index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's easy!! I think you should use a Column and I that PageView for different tabs that you want. and to move between this tabs you can use a row and have some widget in them like iconbuttons or something like I used in bellow code.
The overall structure for this will be like --

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  PageController _pageController = PageController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  int _index = 0;

  static const _iconList = <Icon>[
    Icon(Icons.home_rounded),
    Icon(Icons.chat_rounded),
    Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.youtube),
    Icon(Icons.person_rounded)
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: PageView(
                controller: _pageController,
                children: const [
                  HomeTab(),
                  MessageTab(),
                  YouTubeTab(),
                  ProfileTab(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            CurvedNavigationBar(
              items: _iconList,
              index: _index,
              onTap: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  _index = index;
                });
                _pageController.animateToPage(index,
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    curve: Curves.easeOutCubic);
              },
              backgroundColor: AppColors.color1.withOpacity(.3),
              height: 55,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I used [this](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar) package here for CurvedNavigationBar. You can replace the HomeTab and others with your own pages.